# Distributed query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm learning about distributed query and using SQL Server 2008 to practice.

I got data from the linked server successfully via `OPENROWSET` statement.

Now I want to wrap some data modification statements in a transaction and execute at linked server. How do I do? Is this transaction same with the transaction at local server?

Moreover how do I implement security settings to prevent someone get password login to linked server? The password is a parameter of the `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The query would need to participate in a distributed transaction (requires MSDTC to be installed and configured at both ends and appropriate ports on firewall opened...).  Where possible, try to avoid holding open a transaction across distributed queries.

Might be relevant: [FIX: Error message when you run a distributed query in SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008: "OLE DB provider 'SQLNCLI' for linked server '' returned message 'No transaction is active'"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954950)

[Distributed Transaction Issue for Linked Server in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sqlvillage.com/Articles/Distributed%20Transaction%20Issue%20for%20Linked%20Server%20in%20SQL%20Server%202008.asp)

Update (in response to question raised in comments):

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction):

> Database systems implement distributed transactions as transactions
>   against multiple applications or hosts. A distributed transaction
>   enforces the ACID properties over multiple systems or data stores, and
>   might include systems such as databases, file systems, messaging
>   systems, and other applications. In a distributed transaction a
>   coordinating service ensures that all parts of the transaction are
>   applied to all relevant systems. As with database and other
>   transactions, if any part of the transaction fails, the entire
>   transaction is rolled back across all affected systems.

Comment: Would you please let me know what is difference between local transaction and distributed transaction?